# add 10 days for UNIX timestamps output

Tags: bash, date, timestamps

I've file contain many of epoch / UNIX timestamps  need to add for example +10 days for output date so then I will get new date

and I've create bash script with date command but seems doesn't work

```
for i in `cat stamp.txt`; do
date -d @$i "+10 days" '+%F %T'
```

got error like

```
date: invalid option -- '1'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

since if i run it for date of today is work

```
date -d "+10 days" is work
```

also the convert is work

```
date -d @1469411110 '+%F %T' is work
```

Comment: You could try `date -d "1970-01-01 UTC $i seconds +10 days" '+%F %T'`, which should be equivalent, I think

Comment: @steeldriver Well ... yes, is equivalent. If there is no DST in effect, and a local time is acceptable. Better to use `date -ud ....`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$ date -d @1469411110
Sun Jul 24 21:45:10 EDT 2016

$ date -d @1469411110 '+%F +T'
2016-07-24 21:34:36 EST 2016

$ date -d "$(date -d @1469411110)+10 days"
Wed Aug  3 21:45:10 EDT 2016

$ date -d "$(date -d @1469411110)+10 days" +'%F %T'
2016-08-03 21-45-10
```

Comment: Add a LC_TIME=C, as this: `date -d "$(LC_TIME=C date -d @1469411110)+10 days" +'%F %T'` to avoid locale problems.

Comment: I don't get the same results here (`date (GNU coreutils) 8.26`). The date arithmetic variants (`+10 days`) give me `2016-07-25 07:45:10` instead of the expected `2016-08-03 21:45:10`. Is this a regression bug?